# How to set a display image when sharing a page through Google+?

Tags: html, google-plus

I'm using a share link similar to this:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=[URL]" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

I'm not sure how to set an image to be displayed in the share window.

I have looked it up and tried this solution:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<meta itemprop="image" content="[IMG-LINK]">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't provide us with enough information to work with. What is actually happening with the snippet preview and what do you expect to happen? Do you have a live link we can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I already had the solution, but I was testing locally and Google+ couldn't access my website in order to extract the information. After hosting this on a free server I managed to test it work.

You can see the demo [here](http://testgoogleplus.net63.net/)

Both Google+ and Facebook use the image defined in the `meta item`:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<meta itemprop="image" content="[IMG-LINK]">
```

Also, for extra testing, I added the link as a `goo.gl` shortlink and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Google+ share gets all properties from meta tags and canonical link.like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
```

here is a link: http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/google-share.html